# Is there a Java equivalent of KeyValuePair<T, T> (i.e. a single hashmap 'cell') type?

Tags: c#, java, comparison, hashtable

I used to find these very useful in .NET and I'm unsure of any equivalent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's `Map.Entry<K, V>`, which represents map entries.  I'm not a C# programmer, but this seems like the most similar thing to what you want.

Comment: How can I convert between a `HashMap` and the `Map.Entry<K, V>` type??

Comment: @AlexW: A HashMap contains Entries.  You call HashMap's entrySet() method to see the map entries: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but there's a singleton hashmap:

```
Map<K, V> map = Collections.singletonMap(key, value);
```

Maybe you can describe what you would like to do with it?

Comment: I have a Queue that holds items for checking. How do I map a HashTable to the Key Value pair exactly??